# how to do hide all file extentions?

Tags: .htaccess

Right now im using .htaccess to hide .htm extentions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.htm [NC,L]
```

But i also have php in my site (not to mention javascripts and images, etc..). So how do i change my htaccess to hide all file extentions? (or at least just .htm and .php)

edit: i dont know if it matters, but im on a linux server.

edit2: i tried some of the things i saw on the web and none is worked properly..

Comment: tried this? http://newmediarts.blogspot.com/2007/01/hide-file-extensions-in-urls-with.html Also, sometimes you need to restart your Apache server to see the changes take effect

Comment: Yes i have tried that. It alows you to rewrite to turn any "file" into "file.php", but i need it to work with .htm and .php at the same time:
"file1" ---> file1.php
"file2" ---> file2.htm
So it doesnt solve my problem..

Comment: You could just change all your .html files to .php. There is no difference if you only have html mark up

Comment: @jony please give examples of the "things" you saw on the web as this may help someone answer your question.

Comment: @xbonez thanks for your tips. I changed all my .htm files to .php. i always thought it wouldnt work on (at lease some) smartphones, but your right, if the extension is .php but the file has html only there arent any problems.

Comment: Clients don't need to support PHP for php files to work, even if they contain PHP code. This is because, when a .php file is requested, the php code is executed at the server and only html mark up is sent to the client. (i.e. PHP is server side). Javascript on the other hand is client-side (executed on the client, and hence the client needs to support it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Options +MultiViews
```

should do that trick (replacing your current script). See [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/content-negotiation.html#multiviews)

(You might need to add some rewrite rules to redirect urls with extension to ones without, to prevent multiple urls pointing to the same resource)